# how to attach a file in vb.net email sending program?

Tags: vb.net, email

I'm making a windows form.
Here is my current code:
I don't have any idea on how to link the open file dialog with the file that I am going to attach.

```
    Try
        With OpenFileDialog1

            'OpenFileDialog1
            .Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|" & "All files|*.*"

            If .ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then

            End If
        End With
    Catch
        MsgBox("error occured!")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something similar to..

```
Dim attach As MailAttachment = New MailAttachment(openFileDialog1.FileName) 


Email.Attachments.Add(attach)
```

Comment: how can I define mail attachment